# What software architecture would you need to build a "realtime bidding" ad exchange?

Tags: scalability, tcp

For those not familiar with it, a realtime bidding ad exchange is a relatively new way to allow advertisers to "bid" for the right to show their ad to an individual.

It works like this:  A user hits a website that contains a space for an ad.  This website then pings the ad exchange and requests an ad.  The ad exchange then pings all advertisers that are "subscribed" to that type of ad impression via a REST API that the advertisers must expose, providing information about the ad showing opportunity.  Each advertiser then responds with a "bid", how much would they pay to show their ad.  Advertisers have only 100ms to respond, and whoever wins this auction gets the right to show their ad.

With a typical ad exchange this entire process may occur 2,000 times per second!

I've been thinking about the architecture and infrastructure that must be required for something like this, and it seems mind-boggling to me.  It implies initiating millions of outbound HTTP connections every second, waiting up to 100ms for each to respond, and then processing the responses.

Does anyone have any experience of building an architecture like this?  How can it be achieved?

Comment: Probably just a well-written server in C(#/++) or Java with optimized or in-memory databases.

Comment: Keeping stale data (i.e., caching) is the key to a system like this. "Millions of outbound HTTP connections" sounds problematic. On the other hand, you only write the code once :)... why not try making a million HTTP connections in your favorite lang and see if it brings the VM or interpreter/whatever to its knees?

Comment: @sanity:Why do you want to use web services for this?

Comment: @user384706: What is the alternative?

Comment: @sanity:I mean for the subscription to the ad exchange,the advertisers will send POST to subscribe and receive POST for the bid.So they act both as client and server.How are the advertisers deployed?

Comment: @user384706, You are right that the advertisers are both clients and servers.  The advertisers could be anywhere on the Internet, although it may be recommended that they locate their servers close to the ad exchange (perhaps in the same EC2 zone or something).

Comment: @sanity:Are you supposed to write the code for advertisers as well?Or are you supposed only to define a set of APIs that the advertisers are supposed to expose to communicate with the ad exchange?And the advertisers code is not your responsibility after that?

Comment: We are just defining the API, the advertisers then implement that API.

Comment: @sanity:why use http though?You can use xml over raw tcp.It will be a LOT faster.Is it mandatory to use rest?

Comment: @user384706, why would xml over raw tcp be much faster?  xml or json over a HTTP post request doesn't add significant overhead versus raw tcp.

Comment: @sanity:Depends. First of all over raw TCP you could have a connection with each advertiser and send the messages back and forth over the same connection. With HTTP you would have to use HTTP1.1 to have persistent connections, and still it is not mandatory that the connections would be constantly reused; Additionally the tcp connection would have to be started by the POST for the bid;you would have at least 2 http connections between advertisers and ad-exchange and you would have the HTTP overhead(parsing headers etc).Depending on your needs this could be acceptable though. Is it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may visit

http://inetmgr.blogspot.com/

This blog tried to demystify the technology and the facts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in development that provides a web service exchange:

http://www.instabid.io